# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting, UUID error

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, fstab, uuid

Suddenly my laptop stop booting. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and now when it's booting I'm getting this error. I searched it and tried all solutions I found but still not booting. Please don't mark this as a duplicate and please help me!!

**Error**

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=fcbf606a-0ac2-4da9-b0c6-ee8612ed5048 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a lost of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

Here outputs for some commands I tried;

***sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list***

```
device                             fs_type       label          mount point                            UUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         
/dev/sda1                          vfat          BOOT           (not mounted)                          E467-B07A
/dev/sda2                          ext4                         (not mounted)                          fcbf606a-0ac2-4da9-b0c6-ee8612ed5048
/dev/sda3                          swap                         [SWAP]                                 76b0dd9f-0ee3-4a57-b2f7-085b5681353a
/dev/sda4                          ext4          WorkBench      (not mounted)                          5fc99d45-40ad-400e-993d-10e1c760136c
/dev/sda5                          ext4          Entertainment  (not mounted)                          dc3ed43c-e8df-4a8c-8717-b9ffae68873d
/dev/sr0                           iso9660       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 /cdrom                         2018-04-26-18-43-51-00
/dev/sr1                           iso9660       My CDROM       /media/ubuntu/My CDROM                 2017-01-14-16-54-41-00
```

***sudo blkid***

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="E467-B07A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="7cbed102-d376-4057-8a0d-eb2794ddf36c"
/dev/sda2: UUID="fcbf606a-0ac2-4da9-b0c6-ee8612ed5048" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c12001d1-8c66-42f8-8d2d-f02c2c5535c8"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="WorkBench" UUID="5fc99d45-40ad-400e-993d-10e1c760136c" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="WorkBench" PARTUUID="1b7cff28-a8a9-48ca-a14b-511f78814c59"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Entertainment" UUID="dc3ed43c-e8df-4a8c-8717-b9ffae68873d" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Entertainment" PARTUUID="dd76139e-aeec-4963-98b6-3b2cc76e6c3d"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2018-04-26-18-43-51-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="2b192737" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda3: UUID="76b0dd9f-0ee3-4a57-b2f7-085b5681353a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="56845884-ee7e-4b17-bac0-0033a93641f3"
```

***sudo parted -l***

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   205GB   205GB   ext4
 4      205GB   581GB   376GB   ext4            WorkBench
 5      581GB   994GB   413GB   ext4            Entertainment
 3      994GB   1000GB  6313MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

***cat /etc/fstab***

```
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

***cat /media/ubuntu/fcbf606a-0ac2-4da9-b0c6-ee8612ed5048/etc/fstab***

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=fcbf606a-0ac2-4da9-b0c6-ee8612ed5048 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E467-B07A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=76b0dd9f-0ee3-4a57-b2f7-085b5681353a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

***fdisk -l***

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 622D36C8-88E4-4F3B-85C6-FAF1850F0B74

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624  401051647 400001024 190.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1941192704 1953523711  12331008   5.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda4   401051648 1135054847 734003200   350G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1135054848 1941192703 806137856 384.4G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.7 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b192737

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 30717951 30715904 14.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

***ls -l /media/ubuntu/fcbf606a-0ac2-4da9-b0c6-ee8612ed5048/boot***

I got this output by using Live DVD. I'll add `initramfs` prompt output after this.

```
-rw------- 1 root root  4047147 Oct 23 14:44 System.map-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4048025 Dec  3 22:18 System.map-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1537997 Oct 23 14:44 abi-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1538114 Dec  3 22:18 abi-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217018 Oct 23 14:44 config-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217023 Dec  3 22:18 config-4.15.0-42-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct 16 14:06 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Dec 14 19:38 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55474757 Nov 20 14:43 initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55485262 Dec 14 19:38 initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Oct 23 14:44 retpoline-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Dec  3 22:18 retpoline-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8277752 Oct 23 14:59 vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8277752 Nov 15 19:04 vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
```

***sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2***

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

After unmounted;

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 453874/12500992 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 8062067/50000128 blocks
```

***ls -al /boot***

```
total 136440
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Dec 19 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Dec 19 14:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1537997 Oct 23 20:14 abi-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1538114 Dec 4 03:48 abi-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217018 Oct 23 20:14 config-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217023 Dec 4 03:48 config-4.15.0-42-generic
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Jan 1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Dec 15 01:08 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55474757 Nov 20 20:13 initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55485295 Dec 19 12:18 initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 23 20:14 retpoline-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Dec 4 03:48 retpoline-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4047147 Oct 23 20:14 System.map-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4048025 Dec 4 03:48 System.map-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8277752 Oct 23 20:29 vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8277752 Nov 16 00:34 vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87285/discussion-on-question-by-dananjaya-ariyasena-ubuntu-18-04-not-booting-uuid-err).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and chat...

`initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic` was getting corrupt. Recreating it didn't help.

If you have good backups, you could boot to -39, then delete all of the -42 files in /boot, then do the `Software Updater` app, and then see if you can boot normally then. `sudo rm -i /boot/*4.15.0-42*`

Probably should do a `sudo update-grub` also.

Deleting the -42 files in /boot, and performing a `Software Updater` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a long, long discussion with @heynnema and @kasperd, we found a solution. I had two initrd.img images ( as I know linux kernel images ). One was 42 and the other was 39. we boot into 39 and ran these commands.

`sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
sudo debsums -s`

After that, we deleted 42 image and ran software update.

`sudo rm -i /boot/*4.15.0-42*
sudo apt update`

now it's working. It was @heynnemas' idea. Thank you @heynnema and @kasperd thank you too.

Comment: Please accept my quickie answer if it was (all) helpful. Remember to do a `Software Updater` to put the new kernel/etc back on. Either use the `Software Updater` app, or do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. You're probably running on -39 right now.

Answer (score -1):

Try from root user or

`sudo -i`

`fdisk -l`

then, in your case the error is with `/dev/sda2`
so

`umount /dev/sda2`

`fsck -y /dev/sda2`

`poweroff`

Comment: No, that's not working.

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena there is an error in the post... I’ve given the command in a single line... did u try it the same way... if yes try again once and tell me what happens...

Comment: You can't fsck a mounted disk, and you can't unmount it if you're booted to it. It must be done in recovery mode, or booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. `fsck -f` fixes problems.